# Why is the Actor Kipps, and Kipps the Actor?

Tags: stephen-mallatratt, the-woman-in-black

The stage directions for Mallatratt's *The Woman in Black* indicate that the middle-aged man, "whose name is Kipps, will not be referred to as 'Kipps' but as 'Actor'--even though he clearly isn't one," while the young man "who is an actor, will not be referred to as 'Actor' but as 'Kipps.'"

This seems to be purely a script convention that is not present in the performance, meaning the only way the audience has to deal with it is through being confused by the programme; so far as I can tell it's just a way for the author to mess with the production team.

What purpose does this confusing name convention serve?

Comment: No mention of it on [the cast page](http://thewomaninblack.com/cast) at what seems to be the official website of the play.

Comment: @Randal'Thor And based on the actors' photos, it looks like Kipps is Kipps and the Actor is the Actor in that cast listing. [throws hands up in the air]